# onbutton click display corresponding sql table Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I am attempting to create a program for a medical office, they want a windows web form created within visual studio windows application that will display buttons that the user can select and based on their selection a new form will populate with the corresponding patient info from there they can select their desired patient and edit the details of their procedure.

I am currently having problems displaying the appropriate sql table based on the user selection. I am currently using a gridview in my (ill call it PData Webform) and it will populate all data from my Patients table created in sql.

I am working in C# and my sql connection code is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NATE;Initial
Catalog=MembershipSite;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Fname + ',' + Lname    As
Patients, TestDate, Test, Location, Verified FROM Patients Where Test =
'Echocardiogram' and Verified = 1 Order By 'TestDate' DESC", con) 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Then i am calling my web form

```
{
this.Hide();    
Main ss = new Main();
ss.Show();            
PData sh = new PData();
sh.ShowDialog();
ss.Hide();
}
}
```

Obviously from my SQL statement i just want tests that are = " Echocardiogram " but i am getting a list of all tests.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Also if i were to select any other test besides echocardiogram i want the same "Pdata" table to show but this time populated with that other procedure.

Comment: Your missing the equals sign after: Where Test

Comment: @James I must have lost the = when adding my comment. I made edits but it is still in my code.

Comment: I think the problem is, the datagrid view that visual studio offers attempts to get all data from the selected sql table. When i try to add a query to my table it will bring up a menu button. I do not want that however, i want it to automatically load my selected query based off each button